# MySQL X DevAPI connectors bind dont work with bytes

Tags: mysql, node.js, c, mysql-x-devapi

I have tried both Node.js and C X DevAPI Connector to connect to my Mysql Document Store server. The connection is established, but the server does not seem to understand my search criteria when I use bytes format.

By byte format, I mean that the following Node.js code does not work:

```
const result = await collection.find("field_name = :param")
                                        .bind('param', Buffer.from([12, 4, 0]))
                                        .execute();
```

but the following seems to work and do exactly the same as the above:

```
const result = await collection.find("field_name = [12, 4, 0]")
                                        .bind('param', Buffer.from([12, 4, 0]))
                                        .execute();
```

And in the C world, this does not work:

```
mysqlx_set_find_criteria(query, "field_name = :param");
mysqlx_stmt_bind(query, "param", PARAM_BYTES(bytes, 3), PARAM_END);
```

but the following works and seems to do exactly the same as the above:

```
mysqlx_set_find_criteria(query, "field_name = [12, 4, 0]");
mysqlx_stmt_bind(query, "param", PARAM_BYTES(bytes, 3), PARAM_END);
```

I don't understand what the problem is and why it can't find the document and what is the idea of 'PARAM_BYTES' if you can't compare field value with bytes?

I hope someone can help me and confirm the reason why it doesn't work

Comment: Does not work is not a proper error description! Please provide exact error message or describe unexpected behaviour!

Comment: I have described what is working and what is not working in the code. I even wrote, 'I don't understand what the problem is and why it can't find the document,' hence the issue of it not being able to find the document. Additionally, the title states, 'MySQL X DevAPI connectors bind don't work with bytes.' So, the issue I'm facing is with the bind function accepting raw bytes, but not comparing the field value with those bytes

Comment: Again, does not work is not a proper error description.